# Simple TCP in Java

Tags: java, tcp

I'm starting to learn about networking programming with java. This is my first one but seems like i can't make it right. 
Sever:

```
public class Server1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2508);
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            while(true){
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                String str = br.readLine();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
                if(num%2==0){
                    bw.write("Even");
                }else{
                    bw.write("Odd");
                }
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Client:

```
public class EvenOddClient1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("Localhost", 2508);
            while(true){
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                int num = s.nextInt();
                bw.write(num);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                String str = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I think that my code just can't read the number from client. Thanks for help

Comment: Don't create new `Scanner`s, `Reader`s and `Writer`s in your `while(true)` but before it: you only want to do that once.

Comment: thanks for that. But it doesnt work still.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the integer in binary format (as an `int`) in your client:

```
int num = s.nextInt();
bw.write(num);
```

and you are treating it as a string in your server:

```
String str = br.readLine();
int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

causing an error in the server when sending *"3"* (for example) with the client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Server1.main(Server1.java:21)
```

which closes the connection.

In your client, do this instead, to send the `int` as a `String`:

```
int num = s.nextInt();
bw.write( new Integer( num ).toString() );
```

Comment: @aUsUd Are you sure you started the server and _restarted_ the client after the code change?

Comment: Mine doesn't work ... when i input a number the client just let me input more and more without any result ...

Comment: @aUsUd You restarted both applications? And you are sure that you input your stuff into the client and not the server?

Comment: oh i input in server thanks. I have realized that just now